# Facing Repetition in records when I use multiple relations in Views

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to use views fetch the News and Articles for display on my custom content type "Industries". On Industries content type I have node reference fields to the News and Articles content types.

I've added two relationships in 'advanced' section and in Contextual filter selected Content: NID. I also enabled Distinct > pure distinct settings in the query settings section.
View's Snap are Here : http://prntscr.com/b8mrmp

But still the records are repeating. If 6 news and 10 Articles, then each article is listed for each news node.
Result : http://prntscr.com/b8mscg

Comment: need to required relationship in this view. check "Require this relationship"

Comment: i applied this technique but no luck

Comment: Can you provide the details of your two relationships? The problem comes from there, but the solution depends on how they are setup.

Comment: @acrosman i am using two Custom Content types (News and Articles) in relationships in advanced section of the view. these are included in snap shots above.

Comment: @Esar-ul-haq Qasmi is the details of how you setup those relationships (are they two different fields, are they chained, etc) that would helpful to providing direction.

Comment: @acrosman i created snap shots to explain in details,please find these https://i.imgsafe.org/8467c6b5f1.png and result is here http://prntscr.com/b92kq5

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Comment: i am using this already http://prntscr.com/ba2a9c ,but still the problem persists.